# Compiling with gulp/node/libsass is taking 30+ seconds

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, node-sass, libsass

I'm using Gulp with node-sass to compile my sass. I am also using node-neat and node-bourbon. However, when I compile, it takes 30-50 seconds! What am I doing wrong? I'm not really sure how libsass plays into gulp-sass and node-sass, or what the difference between gulp-sass and node-sass is. In my gulpfile.js, I've tried both `sass = require('gulp-sass'),` and `sass = require('node-sass'),` but they give me the same results. also, I'm using plumber and if I have an error it stops watching. Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    bourbon = require('node-bourbon').includePaths;
    neat = require('node-neat').includePaths;
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    notify = require("gulp-notify"),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('sass/cleverDesign.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      style: 'expanded',
      includePaths: require('node-bourbon').includePaths,
      includePaths: require('node-neat').includePaths}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('sass/'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('sass/' ));
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  // Watch .scss files
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
```

Comment: [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) is gulp plugin for [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass), which is a library that provides binding for Node.js to [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass) which is the C version of the popular stylesheet preprocessor, Sass.

Comment: Have you tried removing plugins to pinpoint what's taking most of the time?

Comment: @Heikki thanks. i've installed gulp-sass. what do i need to do to install the libsass end of things?

Comment: You only need to install gulp-sass.

Comment: Can i just remove it from the gulpfile.js? should i also remove it from package.json?

Comment: By "trying removing" I meant simplifying your styles task. That way you might more precisely where the problem is.

Comment: Btw. don't require things in your styles task. Use `bourbon` and `neat` that you define at the beginning.

Comment: http://laravel-news.com/2014/03/using-bourbon-neat-with-gulp/

Comment: ok. i tried simplifying it and im getting an error. am I close?

`gulp.task('styles', function() {`
      `return gulp.src('sass/cleverDesign.scss')`
        `.pipe(sass({`
          `style: 'expanded'}))`
        `.pipe(gulp.dest('sass/'))`
    `});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**libSass base > NodeSass (main node wrapper)  > Gulp-Sass (gulp    friendly version)**

As for the slow compile time I would double check your version of node, and ensure your node modules for gulp-sass are the newest version. Some critical bugs have been fixed.

For the plumber issue this can be resolved by adding a few more lines to your gulp-sass config. errLogToConsole: true, and .pipe(plumber.stop())

```
 var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    bourbon = require('node-bourbon').includePaths;
    neat = require('node-neat').includePaths;
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('sass/mainScss.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      style: 'expanded',
      errLogToConsole: true,
      includePaths: require('node-bourbon').includePaths,
      includePaths: require('node-neat').includePaths}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('sass/'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(plumber.stop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('sass/' ))
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('styles');
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

Comment: Multiple `includePaths` in sass options object don't make sense.

Comment: Agree with @Heikki. includePaths takes an array. The two includePaths need to be combined. eg: `includePaths: require(...).includePaths.concat(require(..).includePath)`